# Getting the marker texture

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I would like to do implementation like that video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EGMjsYHD7Ak
I would like to use opencv, c++, or pure mathematical stuff. I don't know how really is that app working, would someone give me hints on how to proceed technically on that problem ?

Comment: What *is* the problem? Extracting part of an image, or creating a fancy application with Apple's ARKit, or implementing AR entirely on your own?

Comment: I would use vuforia for the tracking part, but I don't know how to extract the image the market, and get its UV coordinates,..etc of math ?

Comment: I'm gonna give you some keywords: Learn about augmented reality, camera model, pose extraction. OpenCv will help you a lot with those kind of things. and also there is lot of mathematics behind, particularly geometry with little bit of algebra (matrices,..etc). You can start from that book: multiple view geometry in computer vision. It gonna help you a lot.

Comment: @andre If you keep getting more specific, you might end up with a question that's specific enough that it can be answered. (The app only works with colouring pages created specifically for that app, so it knows exactly what they contain. That simplifies things. They also have pre-built animated 3D models, of course.)

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks, I will buy that book now. My question is what are the steps to get the marker, I don't know the steps. So please make an answer like, first you need to get the pose matrix of the marker, then second step you need to do wrapping,..etc  Just give me an answer on the steps and I will continue searching

Comment: @molbdnilo Please guide me :)

Answer (score 0):

What you see in this video is called Augmented Reality.

The app comes with drawing templates which contain features known to the app.
The app will find these features in the camera image.
Knowing that the template is a sheet of paper (a plane in the real world) the app knows how the camera is facing the drawing. using projective geometry it can project that 3d model into the camera image so it looks like it would sit on that sheet of paper.

It all boils down to pattern matching (to find the fiducials that define the plane) and coordinate transformations to do the rest.

Basically all you need to know is linear algebra, some image-processing and some basic programming skills.

Or you use some AR library. Most of them should support things like that. But having the skills mentioned above won't hurt.

Comment: Thanks, what I'm missing is how would I find the fiducials that define the plane and the coordinate transformation, I need the steps please

Comment: I'm using vuforia, how it would help to do that ?

Comment: @andre I don't know vuforia. I'm sure there is a manual. Read it... how to find the fiducials? not sure what is unclear about (pattern matching to find the fiducials) have you even googled pattern matching??  I don't think so. please just do some own research you cannot expect everyone to spoonfeed you. any decent AR library should support something like this out of the box